# Wingdings font in SSMS's column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

I do want to create a column which should has check marks and cross marks.

Here is the part of my query:

```
iif(order_details.order_status = 'Y',char(252),char(251)) as [completed?]
```

After I execute the query in SSMS, I'm getting outputs like this - 'ü', 'û'

But I'm assuming, if change from current font to **Wingdings** in SSMS I'll getting check and cross marks and every outputs will be changed in SSMS. But I only want to change the column  `completed?` .

Here is my result:

[image]

Can any one help me to get check marks and a cross marks?

Comment: Really? Are yes and no that hard to understand in the output? How often are you running and analyzing the output of these queries in SSMS?

Comment: that made sense for me and now I'm sticking with Y and N. Even though I'll feel better if I get check and cross marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible: the display settings can not be specified per column.

If you set the font to one which definitely supports relevant Unicode code points, you can use these characters instead of relying on a legacy symbols font, while still having normal characters available.

For example "Arial Unicode MS" supports [CHECK MARK (U+2713)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) and [HEAVY BALLOT X (U+2718)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2718/index.htm).

Comment: for curious, if I want to get check marks from **Arial Unicode MS** then which font do I want to choose **Arial Unicode MS** or **Arial**?

Comment: Without checking, I would assume that if you want Arial Unicode MS then you should pick Arial Unicode MS. It may be that Arial also has characters for those unicode codeponts, and/or others that would be useful for what you want to display, though the site I've linked to does not list it as such.